# Samsung Remote Test Lab (RTL) : how to bind the device to Eclipse / debugger

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, samsung-mobile

I use Samsung Remote Test Lab (RTL) to test my app on real devices. I perfectly manage to launch the web app and see the device but...I don't see the device in Eclipse.

Consequently: I can't debug and I can't see any log. All what I can do is a drag and drop of my apk file on the device to run my app.

How can I link the RTL device to Eclipse ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

**Actually, now you can** use your own IDE (or ADB instance) to upload your apps to RTL device and debug them. 
That feature is called **Remote Debugging** and you can find it i **Test** section of Client menu.

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlHelpDevice.action?gid=2000&pageord=4#d4e45

**It creates a tunnel between your PC's ADB/SDB instance and chosen device debug bridge.** 
It gives you almost the same access as to your USB-connected device.

Feature works pretty well. However, you need to remember about bandwidth limitations if you want to test bigger apps.

Here is a screenshot of the Remote Debug Bridge in action - type the string in your terminal and it will connect to the Logcat in Android Studios:

[image]

Comment: Did you need to authorize the computer for this to work? When I run the adb connect command, it connects, but shows the device as unauthorized. Can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Dan any solution how to authorize the device?

Comment: Where do you get the localhost port number from?

Comment: You can find it in the "Remote Debug Bridge" window (right-click on the bezel, choose "Test" menu, choose "Remote Debug Bridge"). Necessary connection details are there. 
If you need more advanced debugging (also for free), you may want to check smartdust.me service. They have not only Samsung devices but other brands as well.

Answer (score 1):

The remote testing lab doesn't allow Eclipse to directly bind to their devices. Instead you have to use their RTL client test feature.

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlHelpDevice.action?gid=2000&pageord=1#d4e14